# setOnItemClickListener event doesn't work in Fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to get onItemClick on ListItems to work from a fragment. Here is my code:

```
public class MyBudgetPageMenuFragment extends Fragment {

private Context context;
private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_budget_listview,
            container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) myFragmentView
            .findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    String[] values = new String[4];
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(context, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });

    return myFragmentView;

}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new MyBudgetPageFragments();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.listFragment, fragment).commit();
        break;

    default:
        String message1 = Integer.toString(position);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage("Position: " + message1);
        alertDialog.show();
        break;
    }
 }
}
```

But every time when I select an item, it isn't doing anything or throwing any exceptions. It seems that the event doesn't get registered. I debuged the code and it doesn't enter my event. 
Can someoane tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried implementing in in the fragment itself? In other words try `MyBudgetPageMenuFragment` implement the interface.

Comment: Add a log-output to check if the the click is registered.

Comment: Is the listview enabled and clickable?

Comment: I tried implementing it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The listview is enabled and clickable

Comment: Have you tried:
`ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

Comment: If I tried ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list); I am getting a Binary XML file line #7

Comment: I had problems with doing certain things in `onCreateView(...)` in a `Fragment` and ended up moving certain code to `onViewCreated(...)` instead. This included setting the click event handler.

Comment: I tried this to, my problem is that the click event isn't called.

Comment: Do you any clickable/focusable widget in your list row?

Comment: can you post your xml file for my_budget_listview

Answer (score 1):

Note that the ListView blocks clicks of an item that contains at least one focusable
descendant but it doesn’t make the content focus-reachable calling
setItemsCanFocus(true). One workaround is by disabling focusability of descendants, using

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the layout defining your list item. (First learned of this myself from http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/) Does your layout contain buttons? If so, you'd fall into this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just go the simple way.

In your Adapter class, between `getView` method, initialize `View v = convertView;` then

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "test "+ list.get(position).getS_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to [SO]. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help]. You can also read about [answer] .

Comment: Ok, thanks for the complement. I will definitely try to follow.