# setOnItemClickListener() methode doesn't work in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a viewpager where fragments are shown , inside one of those fragment I used  listView.setOnItemClickListener () method to show interstitial ad whene the user click on a listview item , but nothing work inside this method even a toast msg, here is the code I used :

```
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            mInterstitialAd.show();

        }
    });

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
            super.onAdClosed();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setOnItemClickListener event doesn't work in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749156/setonitemclicklistener-event-doesnt-work-in-fragment)

Comment: you have `mInterstitialAd.setAdListener` inside `listView.setOnItemClickListener` !! This is not the way it should be.

Answer (score 1):

you have `mInterstitialAd.setAdListener` inside `listView.setOnItemClickListener` !! This is not the way it should be. You said - you have a method to show interstitial ad when the user click on a listview item , then directly show the ad. Put the ad clicklistener outside.

**List View Click Listener**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             mInterstitialAd.show();

          }
    });
```

**AD Click Listener**

```
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();

                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // Load the next interstitial.
                    super.onAdClosed();
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }

            });
```

Comment: done , I think the problem is that I used listItemView.setOnClickListener in my custom adapter, but the ads stil not showing